# How to scroll at the bottom of the div onMount using AntD drawer

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

From reading the docs, I can change styling of the body using property `bodyStyle={{}}`.

When you open the drawer I want the scroller to be always at the bottom view? How can I achieve this? The height of the body will be dynamic depending on the content within the body.

[image: Edit awesome-sun-ldxxq]

```
  <Drawer
        title="Basic Drawer"
        placement="right"
        closable={false}
        onClose={onClose}
        visible={visible}
      >
        <p>Some contents...</p>
        <p>Some contents...</p>
        <p>Some contents...</p>
        ....
      </Drawer>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use afterVisibleChange event to scroll by DOM. Use className props to make unique class to query

```
 <Drawer
    title="Basic Drawer"
    placement="right"
    closable={false}
    onClose={onClose}
    visible={visible}
    afterVisibleChange={(visible) => {
      if (visible) {
        document.body
          .querySelector(".demo .ant-drawer-body")
          .scrollTo(0, 9999);
      }
    }}
    className="demo"
  >
```

[Here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-breeze-ztuv4?file=/index.js)

Comment: Ah, is there a way to make the transition look smoother? currently it loads and jumps to the bottom. Is it possible to make have it at the bottom on load?